# Why is ubuntu installer failing to create and mount encrypted partitions?

Tags: system-installation, 16.04, filesystem, encryption, partitioning

Before running ubuntu 16.04 installer I made myself a simple partitioning scheme for encrypted home, encrypted /, and encrypted swap.
After selecting the proper settings in the "installation type" step, ubuntu begins formatting partitions and then fails, showing this:

```
The attempt to mount a file system with type ext4 in Encrypted volume (sda11_crypt) at / failed.
You may resume partitioning from the partitioning menu.
```

The weird thing is that it was supposed to format that partition before mounting it, and it didn't even reach that step.

Before failing, it says:

```
The partition tables of the following devices are changed:
Encrypted volume (sda10_crypt)
Encrypted volume (sda11_crypt)
Encrypted volume (sda12_crypt)

The following partitions are going to be formatted:
Encrypted volume (sda10_crypt) as swap
```

This message is odd, because it was set to also format boot as ext3, and home encrypted ext4, and / encrypted ext4; not just only format swap.

Since 10.10 there's a bug that prevents installer to create encrypted partitions when you are not leaving encrypted swap for the last step, because as soon as installer detects the encrypted swap it begin using it and then it refuses to create other encrypted partitions "because there's an unencrypted swap in use".
Here in 16.04 happens the same, and I detected that the new encrypted swap is used by installer just before saying "couldn't mount ext4 in encrypted partition", but I don't know if there's a connection.

**I would like to install ubuntu on encrypted partitions but it seems impossible with this errors.
Any ideas?**

Comment: Ubiquity installer is missing one step.  It should format sda11_crypt before trying to mount it.  I found a workaround, as ubiquity seems to only format 2 encrypted partitions and no more, I putted my / and /home together and voila!  Later I figured out I just could format sda11_crypt from a terminal before hitting "continue", I think it could works.